# Laravel working with nested collection delete nested branch

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

unable to delete all nested branches where `"product" => null`
Have a query

```
$cartWhere['user_id'] = $user_id;
$cartWhere['site_id'] =$currentSite->id;

$item = Cart::select('product_id','quantity')->with(['product' => function($product) use ($search){
$product->join('product_translations', 'products.id', '=', 'product_translations.product_id');
$product->where( 'product_translations.name', 'LIKE','%'.$search.'%');
        },'product.manufacturer:id,name'])
->where($cartWhere)->get();
```

then I receive collection that has all filtered carts but some of these carts have a relation with product => null

```
  1 => App\Models\Cart {#736 ▼
      ...
      #original: array:2 [▼
        "product_id" => 1
        "quantity" => 2
      ]
     ...
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "product" => App\Models\Product {#785 ▶}
      ]
  }
  2 => App\Models\Cart {#736 ▼
      ...
      #original: array:2 [▼
        "product_id" => 2
        "quantity" => 2
      ]
     ...
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "product" => null
      ]
  }
```

sorry for my English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter them from the results using the collections [filter()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-filter) method

```
$item = Cart::select('product_id','quantity')
            ->with(['product' => function($product) use ($search) {
                $product->join('product_translations', 'products.id', '=', 'product_translations.product_id');
                $product->where( 'product_translations.name', 'LIKE','%'.$search.'%');
            }, 'product.manufacturer:id,name'])
           ->where($cartWhere)
           ->get()
           ->filter(function ($cart) {
               return $cart->product !== null;
           });
```

Comment: when use has i receive the same result, but filter work for me

Answer (score 0):

Along with `with` you should use `whereHas`. So the result will not include any relation with `null` value. So this way you can also avoid the extra `filter` method used.

Comment: also right but i need data from product relation and  translation

Comment: You can achieve it too. By using `whereHas`, you are only filtering your relations. Still, you can fetch the data from any relationship you want. This might help. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence